# pspicture strange effect with \textdir TRT in an RTL document

Tags: luatex, pstricks, right-to-left

In this example, when adding the command `\textdir TRT` the picture is shifted to the right, and I can't understand what's going on here, if we uncomment `\textdir TLT` we get a correct result

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\psset{xunit=1.0cm,yunit=1.0cm,linewidth=0.8pt}
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

a%
\begin{pspicture}(1,-1)(3,1)%
\psframe(1,-1)(3,1)
\end{pspicture}%
b

\textdir TRT
ab

%\textdir TLT

\end{document}
```

[image]

I need to insert a pspicture in an RTL document so I have to go back to RTL direction just after the picture

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\psset{xunit=1.0cm,yunit=1.0cm,linewidth=0.8pt}

\pagedir TRT\bodydir TRT\pardir TRT\textdir TRT 

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

a%
\textdir TLT%
\begin{pspicture}(1,-1)(3,1)%
\psframe(1,-1)(3,1)
\end{pspicture}%
\textdir TRT%
b

%\textdir TLT % I don't want this but it solves the  issue


\end{document}
```

Comment: `luapstricks` is using `\latelua` so the kerning is probably affected by the direction at shipout time.

Comment: This is not a very smart fix, but try for example adding `\AddToHook{shipout/before}{\textdir TLT}`. I'll see which lua function exactly is called to see if there is a better fix.

Comment: @UdiFogiel The code you added solves the problem, but it may have an undesirable effect on others stuffs

Comment: sure, that is why I said it is not a smart solution...

Comment: @SalimBou -- It would be helpful to add "in an RTL document" at the end of your title.

Comment: I just uploaded a fixed version of luapstricks to CTAN, in a day or two this change should reach your favorite distribution. With luapstricks v0.10 this problem no longer appears.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Thanks for the quick fix!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed in the luapstricks package, so on an up-to-date system the code works as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\psset{xunit=1.0cm,yunit=1.0cm,linewidth=0.8pt}

\pagedir TRT\bodydir TRT\pardir TRT\textdir TRT 

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

a%
\textdir TLT%
\begin{pspicture}(1,-1)(3,1)%
\psframe(1,-1)(3,1)
\end{pspicture}%
\textdir TRT%
b

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\psset{xunit=1.0cm,yunit=1.0cm,linewidth=0.8pt}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

    a%
    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](1,-1)(3,1)%
        \psframe(1,-1)(3,1)
    \end{pspicture}%
    b

\begingroup 
    \textdir TRT
    ab
\endgroup
%   \textdir TLT
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

or use package `auto-pst-pdf-lua` and run it with `shell-escape`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf-lua}

\psset{xunit=1.0cm,yunit=1.0cm,linewidth=0.8pt}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
    
a%
    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](1,-1)(3,1)%
        \psframe(1,-1)(3,1)
    \end{pspicture}%
b
    
\textdir TRT
ab
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I need to add a pspicture in an RTL document so the text direction is TRT for all paragraphs I can't use  group for all RTL text

Comment: See edited answer

Comment: A nice answer in which only the option `shell-escape` is undesirable